# How to config docker registry mirror?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have learn tutorial from [that](https://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/).I have create docker mirror in this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 -e STORAGE_PATH=/mirror -e STANDALONE=false -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io -v /Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror:/mirror  --restart=always --name mirror registry
```

And it succeed. Then I start my docker daemon using this command:

```
docker --insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:5555 --registry-mirror=http://192.168.59.103:5555 -d
```

Then I use command to pull image like that:

```
docker pull hello-world
```

Then it throw error in log, and more detail is:

> ERRO[0012] Unable to create endpoint for http://192.168.59.103:5555/:
>   invalid registry endpoint https://192.168.59.103:5555/v0/: unable to
>   ping registry endpoint https://192.168.59.103:5555/v0/ v2 ping attempt
>   failed with error: Get https://192.168.59.103:5555/v2/: EOF  v1 ping
>   attempt failed with error: Get https://192.168.59.103:5555/v1/_ping:
>   EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an
>   unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry
>   192.168.59.103:5555` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the
>   flag; simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.59.103:5555/ca.crt

As you can see, it tell me to add '--insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:5555',But I have added it when I start docker daemon. Anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You´re probably using boot2docker?

Could you try that:

```
$ boot2docker init 
$ boot2docker up 
$ boot2docker ssh "echo $'EXTRA_ARGS=\"--insecure-registry <YOUR INSECURE HOST>\"' | sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#insecure-registry)

Comment: Yeah, I try to add 'EXTRA_ARGS',But it also show me same error.